# PayPal SDK Error:PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR

Tags: android, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am facing problem as follows:

```
{"name":"PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR","debug_id":"e826502719e0f5","message":"checkout-session not created","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR
}
```

Please tell me how can i solve this,
Thank u.